# Find parallel vector with unknown variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having some difficulties understanding this:

> In $\Bbb R^3$ equipped with the inner product $\langle.,. \rangle$,
> let $\vec{AB}=(1,-3,-2), C=(−1,2,1) $
> and for$t\in \mathbb R, X(t)=(0,t,t)$. Find $t^*\in \Bbb R$ such that $\overrightarrow{CX(t^*)}$ is parallel with $\vec{AB}$.

My understanding is that if a vector is to be parallel, the following is true:
$$\langle(1,-3,-2),(0-(-1),t-2,t-1)\rangle = 0$$

Here I have found out that $t^*=-1$, but if you insert $t^*=-1$, you get that $\vec{AB} = \overrightarrow{CX(t^*)}$. Are the vectors parallel? I understand that they are the same not parallel?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's not easy to picture yourself in $\Bbb R^3$; you can simplify your exercise by taking $\vec{AB}=(1,-3), C=(-1,2)$ and $X(t)=(0,t)$. If you make a drawing, everything will become clear. And then you can go back to $\Bbb R^3$ and your original exercise. Anyway, the purpose of this exercise is to create representations, in other words to make drawings.

Comment: i have made the drawings of the vectors computer aided,  but i still dont know how to solve the problem, if t = -1 then the vector CX =[1,-3,-2] which is the same as vector AB

Comment: $\langle (1,-3,-2),(1,t-2,t-1)\rangle = 1-3(t-2)-2(t-1)=9-5t$ and $9-5t=0\iff t=\frac95\neq-1$. Did you make the drawing with the simplified data that I proposed ? Even if the help of a computer is invaluable, here we can even do without it and it is very formative.

Comment: I made the drawings, i now understand more about parallels vectors, but could you please explain a bit more detailed the equation you did to find t=9/5?

Comment: $\langle (\color{green}1,-3,\color{red}{-2}),(\color{green}1,t-2,\color{red}{t-1})\rangle = \color{green}1-3(t-2)\color{red}{-2(t-1)}$

Comment: $-3(t-2)=-3t+6; -2(t-1)=-2t+2; 1-3t+6-2t+2=1+6+2-3t-2t$

Answer (score 3):

*Just a small remark:*

- Suppose that $u,v$ are vectors in the space ${\bf R}^{n}$, then by definition $u$ and $v$ are parallels vectors if there exists a scalar $k$ non zero such that $u=kv$.
- Suppose that $u,v\in {\bf R}^{n}$ are no zero vectors, then if $u\cdot v=0$, then $u$ and $v$ they are orthogonal vectors.

---

There are some things that are not clear in what you wrote. You write that since they are parallel, the dot product between the vector $(1,-3,-2)$ and the vector $(1,t-2,t-1)$ is $0$, but that is not true. If you impose the dot product equals to zero, then you arrived orthogonal vectors as I said in the remark. Now, you said that "here I have found out that $t=−1$" but using the dot product equals to zero to arrived to $t=9/5$ which is the value of $t$ for what $\vec{CX}$ and $\vec{AB}$ are orthogonal vectors. On other hand if you define $t=-1$, then $(1,t-2,t-1)$ is just $(1,-3,-2)$ and then indeed $\vec{CX}=(1)\vec{AB}$ and then by definition they are parallels vector if you setting $t=-1$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the vectors are orthogonal ?

Comment: No. You wrote "if a vector is to be parallel, so the following 'the dot point' is equals to zero" but the dot point equals to zero means orthogonal. You are confusing the orthogonal vectors with parallel vectors, that is the reason because I wrote the differences.

Comment: @HwT I added more details to my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderXander : I think we need drawings: I proposed some in $\Bbb R^2$ with simplified data, and why not use geogebra 3D for drawings in $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: I now understand the differences between orthogonal and parallels vectors,  but im still a little stumbled about  the equation Stéphane provided to find t = 9/5

Answer (score 1):

A major mathematical step when you do not understand something in mathematics is to simplify. As stated in the comments:

[image]